# How can I draw a fish using VML?

Tags: vector-graphics

I want to draw two fish using Vector Markup Laguage (VML).
The mouth of one of them is open and the mouth of the other one is closed.
The fish that I want to draw are something like the following pictures:
[Picture of fish with a closed mouth](http://www.kidsfront.com/how_to_draw/new_img/25-8.gif)
[![Picture of a fish with an open mouth][۲]][۲]
By the way, sorry if the pictures are not displayed. I uploaded the pictures, but when I posted my question, the pictures weren't displayed in the question's text.

Comment: How can you draw a box using VML? A circle? A PAC-MAN face?

Comment: @user2864740 No, a picture of fish. For example, you can visit the following URL to see a picture of fish:
http://www.kidsfront.com/how_to_draw/new_img/25-8.gif

Comment: @user2864740 Do you mean it's impossible to draw a fish using VML?

Comment: My question wasn't if **VML can draw a box**; my question is, **can *you* draw a box** in VML? Start small, work up. *Once you can draw the box*, it's just a matter of adding a circle or an arc or some lines or whatever you want to make the fish.

Comment: I know how to draw a rectangle in VML. I should use <rect> element to do this. I can also use the <roundrect> element to draw a rectangle with rounded corners. Plus, I can use the <oval> element to draw an oval or a circle. But I should research about arcs and curves in VML.

Comment: Great! How about lines? The fish outline can be made with 4 lines, with 2 small arcs for the tail. Another arc for the "belt", and two circles for the eyes. Put the box on the fish's head as a hat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157633/discussion-between-javad-bayat-and-user2864740).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded to draw a fish using VML.
This is the code that I used:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:200;top:200;" id="fish">
    <!-- The fish outline -->
    <v:line strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" from="71,0" to="0,71"></v:line>
    <v:line strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" from="0,71" to="71,142"></v:line>
    <v:line strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" from="71,0" to="191,120"></v:line>
    <v:line strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" from="71,142" to="191,22"></v:line>
    <!-- The fish's "belt" -->
    <v:arc style="width:40;height:142;position:absolute;left:48;top:0;" startangle="20" endangle="160" strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px"></v:arc>
    <!-- The fish's eye -->
    <v:oval strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" style="width:25;height:35;position:absolute;left:50;top:27;"></v:oval>
    <v:oval fillcolor="black" style="width:10;height:15;position:absolute;left:55;top:40;"></v:oval>
    <!-- The fish's tail -->
    <v:arc strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" startangle="0" endangle="85" style="rotation:46;flip:y;width:45;height:100;position:absolute;left:134;top:35"></v:arc>
    <v:arc strokecolor="black" strokeweight="1px" startangle="0" endangle="85" style="rotation:46;width:45;height:100;position:absolute;left:134;top:7"></v:arc>
</div>
```

I put the VML elements that I used to create the fish within a DIV element. But I didn't put them within a v:group element. Because if I do so, the fish is not displayed on my program's window. I don't know why.